# MYSQL populate foreign id with value

Tags: mysql, database-design

[image: Printed table]

I have a printed table here, and I issue a query to attempt to join the tables where the Tech_id, clients_id, job_id, part_id should populate with corresponding key in their tables / column too.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT * FROM work_orders, technicians as tech, parts_list as parts, job_types as    job, clients as client 
LEFT JOIN technicians ON tech_id = technicians.tech_name
LEFT JOIN parts_list ON part_id = parts_list.Part_Name
LEFT JOIN job_types ON job_id = job_types.Job_Name
LEFT JOIN clients ON clients_id = clients.client_name
```

I've messed around with multiple different variations, this one seem to be syntax correct, but now I'm getting: **Column 'clients_id' in on clause is ambiguous**

I'm sure that it will happen for not only clients but maybe others. I want to be able to print the table as in the picture above, but with the clients listed. Is it possible to be done via one query as well? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems.

First (this might not be your problem, but that's a "good practice"), you shouldn't use SELECT *, as you could indeed have a field with same name in different tables.

This is one (of the many) good reason to avoid * in a Select clause.

Then, your main problem is that you select tables in your from clause, and then again by joining.

Problematic line :

```
FROM work_orders, technicians as tech, parts_list as parts, job_types as    job, clients as client
```

So (I don't know your table structure, so they may be errors, but you've got the idea)

```
SELECT 
  w.client_id, 
  t.tech_name
  --etc 
 FROM work_orders w
LEFT JOIN technicians t ON c.tech_id = t.tech_name
LEFT JOIN parts_list  p ON c.part_id = p.Part_Name
LEFT JOIN job_types j ON w.job_id = j.Job_Name
LEFT JOIN clients c ON w.clients_id = c.client_name
```

Comment: do i replace w.client_id with work_orders.client_id? Or just type w.client_id?

Comment: @Bain as you want, if you put an alias on your table (like I did with `FROM work_orders w` then use the alias. If you don't want any alias, don't use any !

Comment: @Bain to be honest, as said, alias or table name can be wrong in my answer, as I don't know your table structure.

Comment: OHHH So i can use the alias in the select clause and define it in from clause. That was what I misunderstood. THANK YOU.

Comment: @Bain oh, yes, you can do that  (or in a join clause also)

Answer (score 0):

This means that clients_id exists in multiple tables. You need to specify which one you want. So if you for example want the clients_id of the clients table, do SELECT clients.clients_id

If all the fiels listed in your question are in the clients table you could do:

```
SELECT clients.* FROM work_orders, technicians as tech, parts_list as parts, job_types as    job, clients as client 
LEFT JOIN technicians ON tech_id = technicians.tech_name
LEFT JOIN parts_list ON part_id = parts_list.Part_Name
LEFT JOIN job_types ON job_id = job_types.Job_Name
LEFT JOIN clients ON clients_id = clients.client_name
```

Comment: I tried the clients.* , still showing as ambiguous. The Work Order table is what I want to have output, referencing multiple foreign keys within it (but populated to the query) if I explained correctly.

Comment: You need to specify which client_id it is as well
`LEFT JOIN clients ON clients_id = clients.client_name
` Maybe `LEFT JOIN clients ON client.clients_id = clients.client_name`?

Comment: The "real" problem is that clients table (as others, but client_id is probably the first "ambiguous" column) is in the FROM clause AND in a LEFT JOIN clause.

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus I think the OP is confused how to join tables. He joins them with the FROM clause and through the LEFT JOIN which is contradicting as well actually...

Comment: @bicycle yes. And that's what's raises an amibiguity.